# Magento 2 Override Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro::isAvailable()

Tags: magento2.3, paypal-payflow-pro

I want to override isAvailable() method of Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro.php

I have tried below steps but it is not working for me.

*app/code/Moduleoverride/Payflowpaypal/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Moduleoverride_Payflowpaypal" setup_version="1.0.1">
</module>
</config>
```

*app/code/Moduleoverride/Payflowpaypal/registration.php*

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Moduleoverride_Payflowpaypal',
__DIR__
);
```

*app/code/Moduleoverride/Payflowpaypal/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro" type="Moduleoverride\Payflowpaypal\Model\Payflowpro" />
</config>
```

*app/code/Moduleoverride/Payflowpaypal/Model/Payflowpro.php*

```
namespace Moduleoverride\Payflowpaypal\Model;

class Payflowpro extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro
{
  public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    { echo "This is working";exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Plugin instead of overwrite whole class.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro">
        <plugin name="sr_payflowpro"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Paypal\Model;


class Payflowpro
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * Payflowpro constructor.
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $this->logger->info(__METHOD__);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Not tested code.**